# Can I get Linux into 'Party/Kiosk-Mode' like status?

Tags: linux, kiosk

I want to create a linux user account (in ubuntu or debian or whatever release is more suitable for this) which cannot do anything but just view a pre-determined web page. Kind of Kiosk style so that the user can observe what is going on from that web page but; cannot execute or write (and this blocking is preferably made also via GUI i.e. user cant minimize or close the browser, cant view any -start menus- )anything on machine.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This website has several tutorials on how to set-up Linux like you want. Note that it may be a bit outdated...

[I'll quote to the "website-only" version](http://users.telenet.be/mydotcom/howto/linuxkiosk/webterm.htm), but do check the site for more info.

> This is part of an experiment to use
>   Linux as a kiosk system. 'Kiosk
>   System' can mean a couple of things,
>   but here we assume that it's a
>   computer that runs just one
>   application - a web browser - and does
>   not allow the user to do anything else
>   but use that browser. That way, the
>   computer can be left unattended, e.g.
>   in public places (public libraries,
>   ... )
>
> One of the appoaches often taken to
>   accomplish this, is to install
>   Windows, then lock it down and present
>   the user with a limited menu-like user
>   interface - often with specilised
>   software (e.g. WinU). But that feels a
>   bit like wasting resources and money :
>   you'd have to buy a Windows License
>   for a computer that will hardly be
>   used (just a browser ...), and on top
>   of that you pay for additional
>   software to make it run nothing but
>   that one browser. So we looked at it
>   from a different angle : is this
>   something Linux could do, without all
>   the overkill ?
>
> **What do we need ?**
>
> To run just a web browser we don't
>   need a full-blown desktop : a minimal
>   x-windows system will do : all we need
>   is 1 window in which the browser can
>   run. This approach is also used in
>   this "minimal GUI" setup for a Linux
>   server where we provide a web browser
>   to take advantage of the graphical
>   front-ends to configure the system.
>   Building on that approach, we will set
>   up a base Linux system (install
>   nothing but the operating system -
>   e.g. Debian 3) and add some x-window
>   components so that we can run a web
>   browser (firefox).
>
> Assuming this computer will be
>   unattended, we don't want users to go
>   and play with it, and we definitly
>   don't want users to crack it or try to
>   get escalate their privilegues or
>   install their own software so that the
>   machine becomes a zombie or what not -
>   so we deny them all access to the
>   system. For this, we use 'Bastille'.
>   Bastille is a program that takes you
>   trough the motions of locking down the
>   system. (see Bastille home)
>
> Finally, we want everything to work
>   more or less automaticvally, so we'll
>   take advantage of runlevels and
>   startup scripts.
>
> **Installing the software and basic configuration**
>
> **the base setup** We install nothing but a base system, then add the
>   packages we need / want. The os used
>   here is Debian 3.0, network
>   installation. We add bastille,
>   firefox, and some components from the
>   x-windows system : just enough to
>   create windows and provide a GUI logon
>   for the user. We also add ssh for
>   remote administration by root and vim
>   to edit text files.
>
> apt-get install x-window-system fvwm
>   vim ssh
>
> System requirements : any pc capable
>   of running (text mode) linux +
>   xwindows. Hard disk space : ... mb
>   (system + software) + swap + room for
>   browser cache /temporary files.
>   Meaning : any old pc will do.
>
> **create a user** We create 1 user (www) with password www. This account
>   will be used to use the PC as a web
>   client.
>
> useradd -m -s /bin/false -p `mkpasswd
>   www SD` www
>
> **the windows setup** Setting up X-windows means you will have to
>   provide some input (monitor, keyboard,
>   mouse, ...). To modify the
>   configuration : dpkg-reconfigure
>   xserver-xfree86 , or edit the
>   configuration file
>   (/etc/X11/X86config-4).
>
> The configuration of the windows
>   environment is found in the user's
>   home directory (~/.xinitrc), and if
>   that is missing, the system default is
>   used :/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/xinit/xinitrc
>   (re. XFree86 HOWTO). (On Debian) all
>   this xinitrc does is call
>   /etc/X11/Xsession, which in turn
>   refers to files in /etc/X11/Xsession.d
>   and ~/.Xsession. In
>   /etc/X11/Xsession.d we find a script
>   99xfree86-common_start with an exec
>   $STARTUP statemenent. Assuming that
>   this is where we can put the programs
>   we want to run in X, we replace exec
>   $STARTUP with 'exec firefox'. This
>   way, Firefox will start as soon as the
>   xserver is started, and closing
>   Firefox will stop the xwindows session
>   as well.
>
> **To do :**  read Debian documentation on how to configure window managers
>   and find out how all these x11 files
>   relate to each other.  find a way to
>   force height and width on Firefox. We
>   want it fullscreen. "firefox -height
>   600 -width 800" should work ?
>   Workaround : run firefox once,
>   configure preferences and windows - it
>   will use those settings the next time
>
> **the runlevels** You may now find that your system now offers a
>   graphical login and starts Firefox
>   rightaway which is what we wanted
>   anyway, except that root prefers a
>   command prompt to set up the system
>   firther. So we change the default
>   runlevel to 3 (in /etc/inittab) and
>   disable the X startup scripts in rc2.d
>   (runlevel 2). Now, the system will
>   boot to runlevel 3 (with GUI login for
>   user www and Firefox started
>   immediately) - root can boot init 2
>   for a command prompt and no worries.
>
> **the bonus** While you have now have a GUI, why not include a screensaver ?
>   'The Matrix' is a nice one.
>
> **the Bastille** Bastille is a program that will walk you through a large
>   number of configuration settings to
>   make your system more secure. Some
>   have to do with networking, e.g. it
>   sets up a firewall which - in the case
>   of a web kiosk - should only allow
>   outgoing http, and accept only replies
>   to outgoing traffic. Another set of
>   settings secures the system as such,
>   by means of 'chroot', modyfing some
>   file system permissions, and
>   tightening the use of SUID. One
>   feature is extremely useful for an
>   unattended PC : setting a (root)
>   password to runlevel 1 ('single user
>   mode', 'root mode', 'recovery mode';
>   'maintenance mode'). In single user
>   mode, one could reset the root
>   password and consequently log on as
>   root - clearly a threath for an
>   unattended computer : just pull the
>   plug or hit the power button and you
>   bypass all security, even with
>   ctrl+alt+del disabled and
>   shutdown/reboot only available to the
>   root user.
>
> Another point is the disabling of
>   printers and /or give the ability to
>   manage print jobs to root only. You'll
>   have to figure this out depending on
>   what this PC will be used for and
>   whether the www user needs printing or
>   not. In this locked down Ubunto/Gnome
>   desktop kiosk system are some details
>   about appropriate settings.

Comment: dated?  oct. 2005.  yeah, you could say it's dated. :)  here's a july-2006 version that uses Ubuntu (same site): http://users.telenet.be/mydotcom/howto/linuxkiosk/ubuntu01.htm  ... tho surely somewhere there's a more recent HOWTO.

Comment: My superuser page crashed on me when I was adding a more recent version

Comment: He could just run Linux of a LiveCD, that fixes a part of the problem!

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using SELinux.  Fedora SElinux policy supports  a special guest user called xguest

> The xguest package provides a kiosk user account. This account is used to secure machines that
>   people walk up to and use, such as those at libraries, banks, airports, information kiosks, and coffee shops. The kiosk user account is very locked down: essentially, it only allows users to log in and use Firefox to browse Internet websites. Any changes made while logged in with his account, such as creating files or changing settings, are lost when you log out.

See the Fedora 11 Security Enhanced Linux User guide.