# GDM guest session for Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, gdm

Every now and then I would like to give my home desktop or laptop to someone to check their mails or lookup something on the web while I am not watching them. I am using Debian 6 (squeeze) and was looking for a more clever solution than just creating an account for them and delete it afterwards.

- I found a solution for Ubuntu at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopTeam/Specs/Intrepid/GuestAccount
- I found another solution for Fedora at [Can I get Linux into 'Party/Kiosk-Mode' like status?](https://superuser.com/questions/54199)

Can someone please point me to a Debian package or a step-by-step instruction to setup a non-persistent account for a graphical session that a logged on user can create by some clicks? The account should be deleted from the system at next reboot or so. I am currently using GDM, but open to KDM or lightDM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark here but wouldn't creating a user called guest whose $HOME points to `/tmp/guest` be enough? The contents of `/tmp` are cleaned out on each reboot (depending on your settings but regulalry in any case).

Unless someone knows why it is a horrible idea, it should at least be worth a try:

```
sudo useradd -mb /tmp/ guest
```

Comment: I went with this solution in the end. Since I did not want the user to logon through ssh, I set its shell to /bin/false. I also added the full-name that is used by gdm: `sudo useradd -mb /tmp -s /bin/false -c "Welcome Guest" guest; passwd guest`

Comment: I would also add `sudo passwd -d guest` so that anyone can log in without the hassle of entering a password (which is the use case of a guest account most of the time). Works on a Wheezy Stable.

Answer (score 3):

All I can offer are some ideas that still need more work:

- Create a normal account with the right permissions where "/home/guest" is on a ramdisk
  so it gets refreshed on every boot
- Add a line that cleans "/home/guest" in the session script
- Bravely try to compile the Ubuntu gdm-guest-session package into Debian

Comment: The first 2 ideas seem to be simple enough. You need a password for the guest user that is shared with all the users on the machine who will give it to a guest, otherwise it is perfect. The 3rd option would be ideal, but I do not have the time nowadays to port the Ubuntu package to Debian. I will try the 2nd option and give you feedback.

Comment: Thanks, but the command-line of @terdon got me in minutes to a solution with the same compromise that your first 2 ideas. Anyways, thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Yes, I am a bit disgusted that I omitted /tmp above.